# PHP - Facebook API will not upload pictures

Tags: php, facebook, image, upload

I am trying to write my own auto poster for a Facebook Page or 2, and it will not upload photos to the page.

Code:

```
<?php
require_once("./src/facebook.php");
require("functions.php");
$f = getFB();

$config = array(
    "appId" => $f['appID'],
    "secret" => $f['secret'],
    "fileUpload" => true,
    "allowSignedRequest" => false
);

$fb = new Facebook($config);
$uid = $fb -> getUser();
$param = array(
    "access_token" => $f['accessToken'],
    "message" => $_GET['msg'],
    "url" => "http://i.imgur.com/lHkOsiH.png",
);

try
{
    $ret = $fb -> api('/me/feed', 'POST', $param);
    echo "Successfully posted!";
    print_r($ret);
}
catch (Exception $e)
{
    die($e -> getMessage());
}
?>
```

It will upload just fine, but the result looks [like this](http://gyazo.com/fb443bea98c18a2da6ca1cc85e71a39a)

How can I get the API to actually upload an image?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simple error you used `/me/feed` which targets the user feed, to target the user's photos use `me/photos` instead, so the final API call would look like

```
$fb->api('/me/photos', 'POST', $param);
```

Comment: Thank you so much! I have one small problem left, which is that the posts themselves dont show up on the page timeline. How can I fix that?

Comment: _"the posts themselves dont show up on the page timeline"_ I didn't understand you, where do they show up then? your own Facebook timeline? is the app in **development mode**?

Comment: Look [at this](http://gyazo.com/29d59bee72d6e6c9cd76dca08b79e58a), notice that you can't see the image anywhere? It's located under the Photos tab, but I need them visible on both the page's timeline AND the users newsfeed.

Comment: those are posts posted using `me/feed`, try `/me/photos` and you will see the uploaded photos in timeline ;)

Comment: I can't say anything, but I did test it and worked fine, try the, are you sure you're using page `access_token`? http://prntscr.com/3ayn6a

Comment: [See this](http://gyazo.com/6140c60530d898402c11473778cc3e68), the photo did upload but it will not show in the page timeline. I've tried viewing as both myself and the page. The access token etc. is all for the page.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/50922/discussion-between-adam-m-and-adam-azad)